# iTunes Connect: Your App "xxx" has one or more issues -> Invalid Bundle

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I uploaded the new version of my app without any problems. Validation was successful. About 2 minutes after the upload I got a mail with the following content:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "-AppName-". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> Invalid Bundle - Failed to read property list: unrecognized option: -AppName-.app/Info.plist plutil: [command_option] [other_options] file... The file '-' means stdin Command options are (-lint is the default): -help show this message and exit -lint check the property list files for syntax errors -convert fmt rewrite property list files in format fmt is one of: xml1 binary1 json -insert keypath -type value insert a value into the property list before writing it out keypath is a key-value coding key path, with one extension: a numerical path component applied to an array will act on the object at that index in the array or insert it into the array if the numerical path component is the last one in the key path type is one of: bool, integer, float, date, string, data, xml, json -bool: YES if passed "YES" or "true", otherwise NO -integer: any valid 64 bit integer -float: any valid 64 bit float -string: UTF8 encoded string -date: a date in XML property list format, not supported if outputting JSON -data: a base-64 encoded string -xml: an XML property list, useful for inserting compound values -json: a JSON fragment, useful for inserting compound values value YES, NO, a number, a date, or a base-64 encoded blob of data -replace keypath -type value same as -insert, but it will overwrite an existing value -remove keypath removes the value at 'keypath' from the property list before writing it out -extract keypath fmt outputs the value at 'keypath' in the property list as a new plist of type 'fmt' fmt is one of: xml1 binary1 json -p print property list in a human-readable fashion (not for machine parsing! this 'format' is not stable) There are some additional optional arguments that apply to the -convert, -insert, -remove, -replace, and -extract verbs: -s be silent on success -o path specify alternate file path name for result; the -o option is used with -convert, and is only useful with one file argument (last file overwrites); the path '-' means stdout -e extension specify alternate extension for converted files -r if writing JSON, output in human-readable form -- specifies that all further arguments are file names ...
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

This is only an update upload. In the past it works with prior versions of Xcode without problems. My actual version of Xcode is 7.0 (7A220). On test devices the app also runs without any problems.

I hope to find a solution this way! Thank you for your time,

kind regards!

Comment: you didn't get any error while uploading it to Apple Store? also did you tried to install it using TestFlight to see if the uploaded build is OK?

Comment: No errors while or after uploading via Xcode. I get the "Subbmission Successful" window. I can't select any build in iTunes Connect. They are gray. After few minutes a get the mail.

Comment: you might need to validate your xCode version https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09222015a

Comment: also I would prefer to upload the version using the application loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you are confusing `plutil` that Apple must be running on your app as part of the validation process.

This is because the app bundle contains `-` characters which `plutil` thinks is a command line option (hence the *help text* it is displaying).

I can reproduce this on my machine (note: I have to use `--` with `mkdir` and `touch` in order to avoid confusing them too):

```
$ cd ~/tmp
$ mkdir -- -AppName-.app
$ touch -- -AppName-.app/Info.plist
$ plutil -lint -AppName-.app/Info.plist
unrecognized option: -AppName-.app/Info.plist
plutil: [command_option] [other_options] file...
The file '-' means stdin
Command options are (-lint is the default):
 -help                         show this message and exit
 -lint                         check the property list files for syntax errors
 -convert fmt                  rewrite property list files in format
                               fmt is one of: xml1 binary1 json
 -insert keypath -type value   insert a value into the property list before writing it out
                               keypath is a key-value coding key path, with one extension:
                               a numerical path component applied to an array will act on the object at that index in the array
                               or insert it into the array if the numerical path component is the last one in the key path
                               type is one of: bool, integer, float, date, string, data, xml, json
                               -bool: YES if passed "YES" or "true", otherwise NO
                               -integer: any valid 64 bit integer
                               -float: any valid 64 bit float
                               -string: UTF8 encoded string
                               -date: a date in XML property list format, not supported if outputting JSON
                               -data: a base-64 encoded string
                               -xml: an XML property list, useful for inserting compound values
                               -json: a JSON fragment, useful for inserting compound values
                               value YES, NO, a number, a date, or a base-64 encoded blob of data
 -replace keypath -type value  same as -insert, but it will overwrite an existing value
 -remove keypath               removes the value at 'keypath' from the property list before writing it out
 -extract keypath fmt          outputs the value at 'keypath' in the property list as a new plist of type 'fmt'
                               fmt is one of: xml1 binary1 json
 -p                            print property list in a human-readable fashion
                               (not for machine parsing! this 'format' is not stable)
There are some additional optional arguments that apply to the -convert, -insert, -remove, -replace, and -extract verbs:
 -s                            be silent on success
 -o path                       specify alternate file path name for result;
                               the -o option is used with -convert, and is only
                               useful with one file argument (last file overwrites);
                               the path '-' means stdout
 -e extension                  specify alternate extension for converted files
 -r                            if writing JSON, output in human-readable form
 --                            specifies that all further arguments are file names
```

Solution: Give the app bundle a better name (one that doesn't contain `-` characters and describes the app better).

Comment: **The status for the following app has changed to Waiting For Review.** _Great, I think the **-** at the bundle name was the problem. In prior versions of Xcode it wasn't, but now. So I renamed it and also I used the Application Loader to upload it. My Xcode was downloaded directly from the AppStore, so I didn't validate it until now. Thanks @all, you saved me a lot of time!